# A couple of questions on using the "Latin Modern Roman 12" font on MS Word

Tags: windows, mac, microsoft-word, fonts

I'm working on a MS Word template for a MSc thesis, but I have a couple of problems with the "Latin Modern Roman 12" font, which I would like to use.

### First issue

On my Mac, I've installed the font (it was installed by TexLive 2013, some time ago), which is composed of three files: `lmroman12-regular.otf`, `lmroman12-bold.otf` and `lmroman12-italic.otf`. On MS Word for Mac 2011, I can see three different entries in the fonts drop-down menu, namely: "*Latin Modern Roman 12 Regular*", "*Latin Modern Roman 12 Bold*" and "*Latin Modern Roman 12 Italic*".

The first question is: What is the difference between using the "*Latin Modern Roman 12 Bold*" font, and the "*Latin Modern Roman 12 Regular*" font with the bold modifier (Cmd+B)?

### Second issue

On another PC with Windows, I've installed the same font files, but the template isn't rendered correctly, as MS Word does not pick up the correct font. In MS Word 2013 I see the "*LM Roman 12*" font. I need to select this font in order to have the template rendered correctly. So, on Windows the mapping is the following.

- "*Latin Modern Roman 12 Regular*" --> "*LM Roman 12*"
- "*Latin Modern Roman 12 Bold*"    --> "*LM Roman 12*" + bold (Cmd+B)
- "*Latin Modern Roman 12 Italic*"  --> "*LM Roman 12*" + italic (Cmd+I)

How can I address this? If the response to the first question would be "no difference", maybe the solution to this second issue is simple: I can stick to the "*Latin Modern Roman 12 Regular*" font, and use the bold/italic modifiers (how they are called, font faces?); since all the styles I'm using are based on the "Normal" style, probably I need to change the font in one place only. Does that sound good?

Thank you and best regards,
Giorgio B.

Comment: Here, I find things work OK with an equivalent (Helvetica Neue) that has linked styles. If I select the Bold font on Mac, Word actually *stores* the name of the base font + bold formatting, but AFAICS picks up the Bold font for display/printing (I checked by saving as PDF and inspecting the fonts used). If I open that file in WinWord (2010) in this case, Word seems to do the correct font substitution despite the name difference. You may be able to check (and change the substitutions) using WinWord->File->Options->Advanced->Show Document Content->Font Substitution.